# Finding all independent connections in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have an undirected graph. Is there any efficient algorithm on how to find all independent connections between two nodes? By independent, I mean that these connections could have common nodes but cannot have common edges.
[image]

In this example, there are 2 independent connections from 0 to 8 (0-2-3-4-8 or 0-5-6-7-8). I tried using Breadth-first search algorithm continuously  while "pseudo-erasing" edges which I've already seen. Problem is that I can go through graph this way: 0-5-4-8 which is not right because I can't make any other path.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try depth first search and collect the path in a path[] and then choose one of  those which have common pairs ..

Comment: You mean all independent sets of paths? The number of these is generally exponential in the graph size. If you want a particular set satisfying an interesting optimality criterion, finding it is likely to be NP hard. If you just want any one, then use erasure with DFS rather than BFS.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan "one of those which have common pairs"? what do you mean?

Comment: @Gene no, I want to get maximum number of paths so that none of the edges are included in some other path.

Comment: Trying standard DFS can't work too. The first-created path was (0-2-3-4-5-6-7-8) so I can't add more paths (0-5-X).

Comment: @P.N i am talking about the edges ..

Comment: Give each edge a capacity of 1 and then solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are interested is to solve min cut problem between a source and sink (the first of the nodes of interest for you is a source and the second is a sink).

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) you can read about the approach to this task. Basically I link to a theorem proving that the max flow between the source and the sink equals the min cut. You are interested in the min cut as this is exactly the minimum number of edges that need to be removed in order to get your source and sink disconnected.

If you run a [Ford Fulkerson max flow algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) you can reconstruct the different paths from the source to the sink considering which reverse edges have capacity after the algorithm is finished. One last note - Ford Fulkerson is classically described in directed graph. To make it work for your undirected case represent each edge as two separate directed edges facing opposite directions. All your initial capacities should be equal to 1.